# How make an image match the size of a windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When doubleclicking the picturebox object contained within this windows form, an enlarged version of the image will appear, stored in a secondary windows form.

[image]

The issue is that the form size will be different depending on the dimensions of the original image. Sometimes the image will take up a portion of the screen or even take up the entire screen. It would be ideal to make the popup image a consistent size.

The secondary windows form is set to be 500 by 500 pixels. What is the best way to correct the following function so that the secondary image appears at a consistent 500 by 500 pixels? Additionally, would it be possible to scale the image to a set amount to prevent the form from taking up the entire screen?

```
private void IdPictureBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var image = IdPictureBox.Image;

   if (image != null)
   {
       PopUpImage pui = new PopUpImage();
       pui.BackgroundImage = IdPictureBox.Image;
       pui.Size = IdPictureBox.Image.Size;
       pui.Show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the following changes.

```
    private void IdPictureBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var image = IdPictureBox.Image;
    
       if (image != null)
       {
           PopUpImage pui = new PopUpImage();
           pui.BackgroundImage = IdPictureBox.Image;
           pui.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
           pui.Show();
       }
    }
```